# List value not recognised in SOQL?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql, list

new to apex & LWC and have come unstuck at what i think should be working....this controller supports a lightning component and is not throwing an errors but is not returning the expected data..........the lightning controller is returning the current record id as used in the first list.

controller:

```
public with sharing class KeyContactsInHierarchyController 
{
   @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Contact> getRelatedList(Id recordId){
        Map<Id,Institutional_Business_Plan__c> pid = new Map<Id,Institutional_Business_Plan__c>([Select ID from Institutional_Business_Plan__c where id =: recordId]);
       
        List<Contact> Conlist = [Select id, name,firstname,lastname, title, LastActivityDate from Contact where key_contact__c = TRUE and Account.Top_Parent_Account_ID__c IN: pid.keySet()];
        return Conlist;
    }
}
```

cmp:

```
<aura:component controller = "KeyContactsInHierarchyController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="ContactList" type="Contact[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myAction}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <lightning:card iconName="standard:work_capacity_usage" title="Key Contacts in Client Hierarchy">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.ContactList))}">
            <lightning:datatable data="{!v.ContactList }"
                                 columns="{!v.columns }" 
                                 keyField="Id"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div Style="text-align : center"> There are no key contacts identified</div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if> 
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

js:

```
({
 myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
 {label: 'Contact', fieldName: 'URL', type: 'url',  typeAttributes: {  label: {fieldName: 'Name' },target: '_blank'  },  sortable: true },
       {label: 'Job Title', fieldName: 'Title', type: 'text'},       
     {label: 'Last Activity Date', fieldName: 'LastActivityDate', type: 'date-local', typeAttributes:  {year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'}},        
         ]);
         helper.getData(component);

 var  Conlist = component.get("c.getRelatedList");
     
        Conlist.setParams    
        ({
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
        });
 }
})
```

helper:

```
({
    getData : function(component) {
        var action = component.get('c.getRelatedList');
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.ContactList', response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Huge thanks for looking at this.
John

Thanks to Moonpie for correcting my formatting.

Comment: I can see that you are not passing parameters before setting a call back in your helper class.  action.setParams({
            'recordId':Passyourrecordid,
          });

Comment: Thanks Paven, i have added this & it still does not work...      action.setParams    
         ({
          recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
         });

Answer (score 0):

Hi john Wilkins can you try this one

```
<aura:component controller = "KeyContactsInHierarchyController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="ContactList" type="Contact[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myAction}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <lightning:card iconName="standard:work_capacity_usage" title="Key Contacts in Client Hierarchy">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.ContactList))}">
            <lightning:datatable data="{!v.ContactList }"
                                 columns="{!v.columns }" 
                                 keyField="Id"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <div Style="text-align : center"> There are no key contacts identified</div>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if> 
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
 myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
 {label: 'Contact', fieldName: 'URL', type: 'url',  typeAttributes: {  label: {fieldName: 'Name' },target: '_blank'  },  sortable: true },
       {label: 'Job Title', fieldName: 'Title', type: 'text'},       
     {label: 'Last Activity Date', fieldName: 'LastActivityDate', type: 'date-local', typeAttributes:  {year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric'}},        
         ]);
         helper.getData(component);
 }
})
```

Helper

```
({
    getData : function(component) {
        var action = component.get('c.getRelatedList');
        action.setParams    
           ({
            recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
           });
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                let records = response.getReturnValue();
                records.forEach(cur=>{
                    cur.URL = '/'+cur.Id;
                })
                component.set('v.ContactList',records);
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rajat, thanks for looking into this but it still not working. I have verified the soql and if the recordid is applied then it should return data - there must be an issue in my controller.